# Page transition with <li> not working

Tags: jquery, html, list, menu, transition

I'm using this code: http://askmike.org/2011/12/smooth-page-transitions-using-jquery-video/ for my page.

Below is my modified code for the Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var request = window.location.hash;
    if(request == '#page-2') {
        $('.page.current').removeClass('current');
        $('.page').eq(1).addClass('current');
    }
        if(request == '#page-3') {
        $('.page.current').removeClass('current');
        $('.page').eq(2).addClass('current');
    }
        if(request == '#page-4') {
        $('.page.current').removeClass('current');
        $('.page').eq(3).addClass('current');
    }
    $('nav a').click(function(){
        var speed = 200;
        var i = $(this).index();
        $('.page.current').animate({opacity: 0, marginTop:0},speed,function(){
            $(this).removeClass('current');
            $('.page').eq(i).css('marginTop',30).animate({opacity:1,marginTop: 0},speed).addClass('current');
        });
    });
});
```

Whenever I put the links in an unordered list, it stops knowing which div to show. I'm no expert with Javascript as I'm just borrowing code, but I'm guessing by putting it in the list prevents the code from knowing which one in order it it (if that makes sense). Any help would be much appreciated. Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YUH6s/1/
Thank you.

Comment: Could you post a simple ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show/demonstrate your code and reproduce your problem?

Comment: At the least post the associated HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your markup index of anchor links is always `0` and your `eq` method only selects the first `.page` element. You can find the index of parent li element instead.

Change:

```
$(this).index()
```

To:

```
$(this).parent().index()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xht3v/